# How to execute a function when two text in different variables are equal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, element

I have two divs, one has class name ".tab" and the other has the id name "#director". I want to execute a function when "#director" element has the text "**left**". *I want to change the background of .tab div to green when it is **clicked*** but if only the #director element has the text "left" in it. so the function i made keeps not executing. Here is my code:-

```js
var leftText = "left";
var directorText = $('director').text();
$(".tab").click(function(){
  if (leftText == directorText) { 
 /*Your Stuff Here*/
 $( ".tab" ).css( "background", "green" );
 }
 });
```

```css
div{
height: 100px;
width:100px;
margin: 50px;
float: left;
background:#ddd;
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab"></div>
<span id="director">left</span>
```

Comment: you forgot to add # since you are selecting with id ... $('#director')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery selector for ids would be `var directorText = $('#director').text();`

Comment: @Axmednuur If this solved your problem can you mark it as the answer? Thanks